# Macro return type to populate drop down list with different value and text values

Tags: kentico

I have a macro that returns a list of ListItem objects with different values in the Text and Value properties. However only the Text property is used. Is there an way of returning distinct "value" and "text" values that Kentico will respect ?

Answer (score 1):

The formats for drop down list items are

something  (this be both value and text)
or
value;text

So make sure you macro can return data in these formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you created this custom macro, and you want it to populate a dropdownlist, could you return a string of the html options instead of ListItem objects?